# Upload photos in background in iPad using NSURLSession

Tags: ios7, nsurlsessionuploadtask

What is the best method to upload multiple photos from the asset library using NSURLSessionUploadTask?

I'm now using NSURLSession background uploads. Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //getting path of documents directory.
    NSString *documentsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempFile.dat"];      //appending file name to documents path.

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
        NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

        _totalBytesToSend += buffered;
        [_dataArray addObject:data];
    };

    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        DLog(@"Can't get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    //work needed here
    for (NSURL *url in _urlArray) {

        if(url != nil)
        {
            [assetslibrary assetForURL:url
                           resultBlock:resultblock
                          failureBlock:failureblock];
        }

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        for (NSData *data in _dataArray) {

            if(![data writeToFile:documentsPath atomically:YES])
            {
                DLog(@"Saving image failed");
            }

            //Prepare upload request
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"my url here"]];
            [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request addValue:[[DTETokenManager sharedManager] loginToken] forHTTPHeaderField: @"X-CSRF-Token"];

            _uploadTask = [_session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", documentsPath]]];
            [_uploadTask resume];
        }
    });
```

Is this a good approach? A problem I'm facing with this is that I'm not able to update a progress bar correctly, in which I intend to show the progress of the total upload process. I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend
{

    //Progress reportpo
    _totalByteSent += totalBytesSent;
    if(_totalBytesToSend && _totalByteSent)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kBytesUploaded object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double)totalBytesSent/(double)totalBytesExpectedToSend] forKey:NOTIFICATION_PAYLOAD]];
    }

}
```

As expected, the progress update is not at all proper :)

Please point out a better approach, as I'm finding it really difficult to find proper tutorials to handle uploads. There are plenty that explain background downloading though.

Comment: Did you want the progress bar to illustrate how many uploads have completed, or rather the upload status of each individual task?

Comment: I have figured out how to track upload of each file.As i mentioned in my answer I'm using just an activity indicator now. Of course, the best scenario would be if i could show the progress of each file as i upload.Also i am now sending the files one by one (instead of using  the for loop as in the code above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i did not get any response from here , i ended up dumping the progress bar all together and adding an activity indicator which stops spinning when all downloads complete